# split different two element attribute into multiple duplicate rows

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml file that contains attribute and data type of attribute like this:

```
<document>
<ROOT>
    <Data X="1233" XType="Integer"  Z="abcd" ZType="String" />
    <Info T="1:30:57" TType="Date" F="xyz" FType="String" />
</ROOT>
</document>
```

and expected output is:

```
<document>
<ROOT>
    <Data X="1233" XType="Integer"  />
    <Data Z="abcd" ZType="String" />
    <Info T="1:30:57" TType="Date"/>
    <Info F="xyz" FType="String" />
</ROOT>
</document>
```

I googled a lot to find solution to split each two attribute..but not found solution
any suggestion? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in **XSLT 2.0** with for-each-group

First use identity template to copy all elements

```
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Than handle `Data` and `Info` in another template to group by there attribute first character.

```
<xsl:template match="Data|Info">
    <xsl:variable name="currentelement" select="local-name(.)"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="@*" group-by="upper-case(substring(local-name(.), 1,1))">
     <xsl:element name="{$currentelement}">
         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"></xsl:copy-of>
     </xsl:element>   
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

You can see tranformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtF

Comment: Thank you for reply